# Illegal instruction when overloading >> operator

Tags: c++, io, operator-overloading, overloading

So I have a struct and am trying to overload the >> operator on it. The struct is defined as follows:

```
struct Temps {
double max;
double min;
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Temps& t);
Temps() {}
Temps(double a, double b): max(a),min(b) {}
};
```

The overloaded >> operator is defined as follows:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Temps& t) {
is>>t.max;
is>>t.min; 
}
```

This operator is called in code as seen below.

```
vector<Temps> readTemps(string name) {

vector<Temps> temps;
ifstream is(name.c_str());
if (!is) error ("can't open input file",name);

while(is.peek() != EOF) {
    Temps t;
    is >> t;
    temps.push_back(t); 
}
return temps; 
}
```

I don't get any errors in vsCode or when compiling, but when debugging it gets to the end of the istream& function, and then gives the error message:
"Exception has occurred: W32/0xC000001D
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF66FB31D9A in debug.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction."
I really don't know what to do about this. I've tried to change the constructor, but it doesn't seem to affect this.

Comment: Note the return type of `operator>>`. Note the lack of a `return` statement in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks, adding "return is" solved it. I was kinda confused, because for another problem in the assignment I overloaded >> with return type ostream, but I didn't return any value and had no problems.

Comment: You should add `return is;` there as well. Any function with a return type (except main) has to return something in every branch of the code otherwise its undefined behavior. So you could summon a demon and it would be OK according to standards.